# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when access google.com

Tags: networking

When I am access `google.com`, it give me this tips:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

this is the detail output:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.google.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: ssl371063.cloudflaressl.com

Issuer: COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2

Expires on: Jun 4, 2020

Current date: Oct 8, 2020

PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Help improve security on the web for everyone by sending URLs of some pages you visit, limited system information, and some page content to Google. Privacy policy
www.google.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to www.google.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be www.google.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.

You cannot visit www.google.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
```

and when I access other net like `youtube.com`, it works. I am searching from internet, and try to clear cache, what should I do to fix it?

[image]